# Sites within a SharePoint 2013 HNSC web application not working on one server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, wss

We have two servers on a cluster, say server1 and server2. We have these for load sharing and backup if one server is down.

We have many HNSC web Apps each containing a bunch of sites. 
One particular HNSC web application is not working on one server (server2) but only works on server1. It was working fine till 2 days ago !

Other HNSC web Apps are working fine on both servers. If SharePoint architecture or software updates were the case, then no other web app or site collection would be working on the faulty server, but others are working fine.

The sites within this particular web App are giving the following error in browser window when they hit server2:

**Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=177673**

When they hit server 1, they run fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a problem with sharepoint software updates on one server. The IT Team had installed updates on one server but not the other.

Reason why only 1 webApp (and Hnsc site collections inside it) were giving error is because they were created after the updates were done on one server.

Solution: IT Team did the updates on the other server as well, and all worked fine.